# Fetch data from Google Cloud Storage in frontend. How to authenticate?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-cloud-platform, fetch, svelte

This might be a very naive question, still here it is.

I want to build a very small front-end project in svelte kit. I do have thousands of json-files that I might want to use. The user can search for an id and the respective json file is loaded.

I, in lack of a better idea, figured that I could place the json-files on google cloud storage. As far as I understand I can make them publically available or not. I do not want that, cause who knows many people start downloading that or so I dont know.

### The issue

Each time the user selects a file I want to send a request to that cloud storage and query the data. In my head I can't get really around on how the authentication could work. There is e.g. this [npm-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) for google authentication. Yet it runs on the server and not the client right?

I'm probably facing some misunderstandings here. I did not find many good and easy ressources on that in the internet. So any help on clearing these issues would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: If your bucket is not public, you need a backend that authenticate your current user (firebase auth, cloud identity, or whatever) and perform the secure api call that you want to achieve (wrap it). You can't directly access to the service in a secure manner

Comment: great:) thank you very much! I do not care at all about the data itself as it is public. I just thought that there were some requests to the data, i had to maybe pay in the end. But if I'm understanding this correctly, anything under 5gb doesn't have a price, independent on the requests?

Comment: You can store 5Gb for free, but the egress is not free. If you serve a lot of traffic, many Gb or Tb of data from your storage, it can cost a lot!

Comment: thanks a lot! Would you have any other idea on where to store that type of data ?

Comment: Have a look to App Engine standard to serve your static file. It's free (no processing) and you have 1Gb of egress per day free also. It's a good candidate to serve widely and at lowest cost traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use firebase auth and firebase storage (to access Google Cloud Storage). It's easy and works fine.
More here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage

Example firebase.js

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { app } from "../firebase.config.js";

const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, auth, db, storage }
```

Example firebase.config.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "example.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://example.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "example",
  storageBucket: "example.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "...",
  appId: "..."
};

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And an example function to list a storage bucket folder:

```
import { ref, listAll, getMetadata } from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "@/firebase.js";

const storageRef = ref(storage);

export async function getList(folder) {
  const metaView = [];
  const folderObj = {}
  const result = await listAll(ref(storageRef, folder));
  for (let itemRef of result.items) {
    folderObj[itemRef.name] = itemRef;
    metaView.push(await getMetadata(itemRef));
  }
  return [folderObj, metaView];
}
```

But if your json files are no larger than 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes), you can also save them as firestore documents and take advantage of the benefits of firestore queries.

Comment: thanks a lot!! One thing I do struggle with to understand: Does every user who just wants to use my site has to authenticate or is it me as as programmer who has to authenticate? Sorry this might be a really naive question...

Comment: In firebase you have to register a project, which makes you the owner. Now you can create, build and deploy your app. And you can add the auth rules and sign-in methods (like e-mail and password) for users to access your app. And you have to add yourself as a user to access the app.

Comment: Can I make it so that no one has to register? Like to pop-up saying you need to register here?

Comment: Your question is not clear! Register for? Yes you can register to become a user. 
An easy one (one time one): ask te user to provide an e-mail address. The user reveives a link which provides user access. 
More here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth